# c# MonthCalendar pintar el fondo de un color en varias fechas

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Bueno me estoy iniciando con el C# y he creado una aplicación de una agenda para practicar con conexión a base de datos MySql. En la agenda quiero que aparezca un monthCalendar con todas las fechas que tengan alguna anotación con el fondo de un color diferente. He usado la propiedad AddBoldedDate para que me ponga la fecha en negrita, pero no me termina de gustar. ¿Hay alguna propiedad que pueda cambiar para que aparezcan los días indicados con el fondo de otro color? ¿cómo puedo hacer esto de forma similar a AddBoldedDate?

Edito: No había puesto el código porque no tiene nada especial, uso el componente MonthCalendar que proporciona visualstudio. Si es conveniente que ponga alguna parte especial, solo decidmelo y lo pongo.

Código del MonthCalendar

```
private void mcFecha_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Evento ev in eventos)
    {
        mcFecha.AddBoldedDate(ev.getEvento());
    }
}
```

muchas gracias

Comment: El MonthCalendar por defecto no tiene opcion para hacer lo que dices. Tendrás que utilizar algun calendario de terceros, por ejemplo [este](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar)

Comment: ese precisamente he intentado usarlo, pero no se como puedo hacerlo, conoces de algún manual o algo donde esplique como puedo agregar ese calendario y usar sus métodos, el problema lo tuve al usar el método void AddDateInfo(DateItem[] info) que no me lo reconocía, había agregado el proyecto a mi programa y añadido la librería usando "using" por lo que el DateItem si me lo cogía pero no ese método

Answer (score 1):

Resumiendo, **no se puede hacer lo que comentas**.

Cómo verás en la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983568(v=vs.71).aspx) la única personalización que tienes disponible es **global** y no hay manera de personalizar de manera **específica**.

En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5049351/1468942) de SOen concurren en lo mismo y la solución es **utilizar componentes de terceros**.

El que te recomienda Pikoh en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29394/c-monthcalendar-pintar-el-fondo-de-un-color-en-varias-fechas#comment47562_29394) es una buena idea y al ser de CodeProject lo podrás integrar sin problema: Aquí el [link](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/10840/another-month-calendar)

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer pero no de la manera "normal",  ya que el control `CalendarMonth` es un control del sistema por lo que aunque sobrescribas el método  `void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)` tu código nunca se ejecutará.

Esta información viene aclarada aquí: [OnPaint Method](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67tdk61t(v=vs.85).aspx)
Y más concretamente en este párrafo:

> The MonthCalendar control is drawn by the operating system, so the Paint event is never raised. If you need to provide a customized look to the MonthCalendar control, you should override the OnPrint method, call the base implementation of OnPrint, and then perform custom painting.

Que viene a decir lo que comento arriba.

Para solucionar esto lo que podemos hacer es lanzar nosotros mismos el evento OnPaint de este control  através `WndProc`y así se podrá ejecutar nuestro código del OnPaint donde podremos ahcer los que nosotros queramos, ya sea modificar el color, como texto, fuente, etc.

Para llevar a cabo al implementación debes crearte un control que herede del mismo `MonthCalendar` y sobreescribir el método `OnPaint` donde deberás implementar el código para que se pinten de un color o de otro, fuente, tamaño, etc.

```
public class CustomCalendario: MonthCalendar
{
    public CustomCalendario()
        : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Dibujamos por ejemplo un rectángulo de color rojo
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 20, 20, 100, 100);
    }

    // Esta parte es muy importante ya que forzamos la llamada al método OnPaint mendiante los "mensajes" de windows 
    protected static int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;
    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
        {
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle);
            PaintEventArgs pe = new PaintEventArgs(graphics, new Rectangle(0,0, this.Width, this.Height));
            OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
}
```